# what is database cloning?

Tags: database-cloning

had been looking towards this "Database Cloning" quite many times.. is it anything different from simply creating a copy of the database... please tell me keeping MySQL in mind...

Answer (score 0):

Definition from Wikipedia:

> A database clone is a complete and
>   separate copy of a database system
>   that includes the business data, the
>   DBMS software and any other
>   application tiers that make up the
>   environment. Cloning is a different
>   kind of operation to replication and
>   backups in that the cloned environment
>   is both fully functional and separate
>   in its own right. Additionally the
>   cloned environment may be modified at
>   its inception due to configuration
>   changes or data subsetting.

MySQL Documentation for cloning database objects:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio-cloning-database-objects.html